# Determine table during runtime with Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Is it possible to determine the table to use during runtime with [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)?
Or do I have to fill a dataset?

```
var results = from r in db.Table <-- change whenever I need to during runtime
                      select r;
```

If not, I would like to know why, and if so, I would like to know how. An working example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're looking for [`DataContext.GetTable(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310460.aspx). You'll need to know the entity type associated with the table, and then call that method.

Obviously the result won't be strongly typed, but it will be the right table.

If you know the type *generically* (e.g. you can put this into a generic method) you could use [`GetTable<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx) instead, which *will* give you a strongly-typed result.

Comment: i looked at your rep history, do you get to sleep? ever?

Comment: @LiranElisha: There used to be a question on Meta about when I sleep, but I think it got deleted. Generally between midnight and 6 (London time) during the week and midnight and 7 at the weekends.

Comment: @Jon Didn't you also say you didn't sleep in Jon Skeet Facts?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: Someone else said that, not me :)

Comment: @user2603738: No, because you've given us no context whatsoever. We don't know how you're trying to use the results, or how you know the table, etc.